# Deserializing enum value with Json.NET

Tags: c#, json, enums, json.net, deserialization

I have a JValue deserialized from JSON and this value represents an enumeration. Consider these two cases:

```
JValue value = ...

object o1 = value.ToObject(typeof(MyEnum));
object o2 = value.ToObject<MyEnum>();
```

o1 is of type integer and holds a numeric value of an enum

o2 is of type enum and holds enum value

Why does ToObject method work differently in these two cases?

Answer (score 2):

Lets say that `MyEnum` looks like this:

```
public enum MyEnum
{
    First = 1,
    Second,
    Third
}
```

and that the `JValue` is defined like this:

```
var value = new JValue(MyEnum.First);
```

When you make  call to the following line:

```
object o1 = value.ToObject(typeof(MyEnum));
```

you are making a call to the non-generic overload of `ToObject` method. This method, in the case of enums, resolves the underlying type of the enum, which in this case is `int` and casts the object to that value. That's why it returns numeric value. (1 in this case).

When you make a call to the generic overload of `ToObject` method:

```
object o2 = value.ToObject<MyEnum>();
```

the result is obtained from the `JValue` and it is 1 again, but before returning the value, it is casted to the type of the generic type parameter.

To be more clear, here is how the generic overload of `ToObject` method looks like:

```
public T ToObject<T>()
{
    return (T)ToObject(typeof(T));
}
```

It calls the non-generic overload (which we used in the first case), but it casts the result to `T` before returning it. That's why in the first case we get numeric and in the second case enum value.